# COGNOS 10.2.1 connecting to IMS by JDBC

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, ims-db

When i tried to make a datastore connection from COGNOS BI 10.2.1 to IMS, I am getting the below error

" XQE-DS-0006 Unable to logon to the data source. 
  com.ibm.ims.dli.PSBCreationException: An error occurred accessing the PSB:       com.ibm.ims.dli.DLIException: Unable to retrieve metadata information for    Database (PSB), CORSEPSB,   from the IMS Catalog.
  An error occurred accessing the PSB: com.ibm.ims.dli.DLIException: Unable to retrieve metadata   information for Database (PSB), CORSEPSB, from the IMS Catalog.
  Unable to retrieve metadata information for Database (PSB), CORSEPSB, from the IMS Catalog.
  com.ibm.ims.drda.base.DrdaException: The PSB resource, CORSEPSB, requested by the GUR is not found in   the IMS Catalog. Verify that the correct IMS catalog is being accessed.  AIB return code (AIBRETRN):   108 AIB reason code (AIBREASN): 344
  The PSB resource, CORSEPSB, requested by the GUR is not found in the IMS Catalog. Verify that the   correct IMS catalog is being accessed.  AIB return code (AIBRETRN): 108 AIB reason code (AIBREASN): 344".

We have catalog in our IMSV13 environment.

I have generated the PSB, DBD, ACB members and these generated members are there  in their respective libraries and even my DBD is in the catalog DB IMSV13.SDFSRESL.

Please guide me to solve the above issue.

Comment: When you say 'datastore' connection, it sounds like you are trying to use it for the Content Store, Audit Store, notification store, mobile store, etc.  Is that the case?  Or are you connecting to IMS for Reporting as a 'Datasource' only?  This is an important distinction, as IMS is only supported as a 'datasource' in Cognos 10.2.1 See supported environments: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27027080  also IMS best practices http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-pp-infrastructure-cognos_specific-page630/

Answer (score 0):

The 0108/0344 return and reason codes that you received indicate that the PSB CORSEPSB is not in your catalog. There are two possible reasons why this is happening:

**1. The information is not in the catalog**

In addition to running the DBDGEN, PSBGEN and ACBGEN steps, you'll need to populate the IMS catalog from your ACBLIB. This can be done using the IMS catalog populate utility ([DFS3PU00](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPH2_14.1.0/com.ibm.ims14.doc.sdg/ims_catalog_definition_pop_dfs3pu00.htm)) or the combined ACBGEN/Populate utility ([DFS3UACB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPH2_14.1.0/com.ibm.ims14.doc.sdg/ims_catalog_definition_pop_acbgen.htm)). You can then validate that the resource is in the IMS catalog by querying the catalog database (DFSCD000) directly to see if it's in there.

**2. The resource is not active**

The other possibility is that CORSEPSB is in the IMS catalog however it hasn't been marked as active in your ACBLIB. When metadata lookup occurs, it retrieves the resource information in the IMS catalog that corresponds with what's running on your system which is based on the ACBLIB. To fix this issue, you would need to run an online change command. You can do either a member online change or a global online change.